# Make renderer.label responsive Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

This is in connection with my previous post ([Add design to plotLabel Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45210835/add-design-to-plotlabel-highcharts)), Is there a way to make renderer.label responsive? see my screenshot below for further details. Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x8vhp0gr/

[image]

```
 plotlabel = yAxis.plotLinesAndBands[0].label;
        plotbandLabel.animate({
            y: yAxis.toPixels(y) - labelOffset
          }, {
            duration: 400,
            step: function() {
              this.attr({
                text: yAxis.toValue(this.y + labelOffset).toFixed(2)
              })
            },
            complete: function() {
              this.attr({
                text: y.toFixed(2)
              })
            }
          }),


          plotLine.animate({
            translateY: newY
          }, 400);
```

Comment: Take a look at this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45279448/make-chart-renderer-path-as-plotline-highcharts/45284216#45284216. Instead of a plot line, path along with label is created and animated.

Comment: i've checked the jsfiddle and your answer there is also not responsive, check this screenshot https://s19.postimg.org/b9s22ngdv/notresponsive.png

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what kind of responsiveness you want to add, beside the one already added in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a64e5qkq/?